# Shortcode execution with ACF variable

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I want this acf field to execute the ID of the shortcode associated with it.

I tried with this code that uses the ID of the shortcode chosen in the back-office.

It doesn't display anything, but my shortcodes, which are in fact reusable blocks, are well configured.

```
$choix = get_field( 'choix' );
if ( $choix ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[reblex id="'. $choix .'"]');
}
```

The shortcodes are like : [reblex id='6384']

The ACF field only shows the ID of the style : 6384

Comment: So a `echo do_shortcode('[reblex id="6384"]');` in that same position actually shows what you want, yes or no?

Comment: Yes, exactly! This displays my shortcode.

I would like the shortcode chosen in the back-office with ACF to be executed with this php code

Comment: Do a `var_dump($choix);` to verify that actually contains what it should.

Comment: J'ai ça qui s'affiche en front : ```array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "6384" }```

Comment: What context does this execute in? Template? Some hook/filter?

Comment: I run the ACF field in question "choice" so it's a shortcode in the product description